# Android: Bitmaps and Performance

Tags: android

I have been reading a lot of posts here on SO about image loaders, bitmaps and asynctaks to download and display images. When dealing with a small amount of bitmaps, my image loader is fine, it downloads the image and display it to the user, but it also save a WeakReference in a HashMap that I use as a cache and also save the image in the SD card in case the user needs that image to be displayed later without having to download it again. So far this is fine, my apps were working totally ok.

Now I started working on a new apps where the number of images to be displayed in the same screen is greater than 50 (for example), in this case the screen does not scroll smoothly, and I also find the FPS lower than the usual, delivering a bad user experience. I am running out of ideas on what to do next. Does anyone have an advice?

Using WeakReference instead of WeakReference improve the memory usage and also the user experience?

I am no scaling the bitmaps as I download them since they are already thumbnails, should I be scaling them? The images can occupy a maximum of 50% of the width of the screen.

Right now my main concern is not related to the download time, my concern is regarding the number of bitmaps being displayed and how smooth the scroll should be. I am not using gridview, I am using masonry component from http://code.google.com/p/android-masonry

What kind of suggestions do you guys have to me? Where should I start be looking at?

Thanks
Thiago

Comment: I normally use DroidFu's ImageLoader API, which makes use of caching. It's worked very well for me and might be worth checking out: https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu

Comment: caching and downloading the images right now are not the problem, the problem is that the performance of the UI decreases a lot with lots of bitmaps being displayed at once. For two or three images, its fine, but I am displaying more the 50 bitmaps, and the biggest image has width 50% of the screen, or 158dip, but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used DDMS on your app yet? Is you app thrashing from Garbage Collection?

You only have a finite amount of memory and Bitmaps are difficult to manage. You mention in your comments that the cache is not the problem, but if you're running low on memory you don't want to keep any more Bitmaps around than you need. You may only be drawing 50 or so images at a time but your cache may be holding 100 bitmaps and consuming memory.  I wouldn't bank on WeakReference solving the problem for you, especially with Bitmaps. Have you made a rough estimate of how much memory the 50 images are consuming?

My experience related to this has been with building a custom map application that has to display many map tiles that are 256x256. So I went through much of the same thing you're going through now. You do need some form of a cache to keep the UI responsive, so the user is not waiting for the image over the network.  But after trying a hard cache, then a soft cache, and even a dynamic cache (combo of hard and soft memory cache), I finally decided on only caching what was needed and throw away the rest. So I calculate if any of the current images in memory are valid in the next rectangle (say the user is scolling), if they are, I reuse them, if not I throw them away - that's the only memory cache I keep.  Images I need to download from the network are written to the SDCard and pulled into memory only when needed.

Another thing to look at is [BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig). Try pulling in all your images at RGB_555 if you can. The default is ARGB_8888 which is twice the size as RGB_555.

Finally make sure the Bitmaps ARE the problem. Use DDMS. It often seems what was once a difficult problem turns out to be something very simple - it's always the overlooked simple stuff that'll keep you up late at night.

Comment: many thanks for you comments. When you say "hard cache" do you mean that you are caching the images in the SD card right? I will take a look at the DDMS and try to find out if the bitmaps are the problem or not.

Comment: By hard cache I mean a memory cache that isn't using Soft/Weak ref.  Probably not they correct term, but that's what I mean

Comment: gotcha, I found this class from google (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html), they do this hard/soft memory cache, I will take a look at it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check out this new class on Android Training: [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). It discusses many things related to your questions such as memory usage, image scaling, smooth scrolling (only for components like ListView and GridView though) and using a memory and disk cache to improve performance. In particular, this section (from [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)):

> Note: In the past, a popular memory cache implementation was a SoftReference or WeakReference bitmap cache, however this is not recommended. Starting from Android 2.3 (API Level 9) the garbage collector is more aggressive with collecting soft/weak references which makes them fairly ineffective. In addition, prior to Android 3.0 (API Level 11), the backing data of a bitmap was stored in native memory which is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash.

As mentioned in the other answer, instead, a cache of strong references is preferred using something like the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class.